# How can i do Text extraction in Nodejs with good quality?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ocr, tesseract

I want to extract the text from an image. it was a PDF and i convert it to a tiff image.
The image was good quality.I want to extract the word GeNeSys-ID: and the number after it.

I tried with tesseract.js but the extraction was not good then i tried with node tesseract ocr and the extraction was better but not as i want. I also tried to use preprocessing but it doesn't help.
This is the code with node tesseract ocr

```
//const tesseract = require("tesseract.js");
const tesseract = require("node-tesseract-ocr")
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const config = {
  lang: "deu",
  oem: 3,  // try different OEMs to see which one produces the best results
  psm: 4,  // try different PSMs to see which one produces the best results
}
let moduleInfo = {
  dirPath: '',
  pdf: 'a.pdf'
};

exec("gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r600 -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dColorConversionStrategy=/saturation -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile=" + moduleInfo.dirPath + "output.tiff " + moduleInfo.dirPath + moduleInfo.pdf, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
  tesseract
  .recognize("output.tiff", config)
  .then((text) => {
    console.log("Result:", text)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message)
  })
});
```

and this is some input examples :
[input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx29O.png)
[input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPV70.png)